# Adding a bespoke priced line item (handling cost) to shopify cart from external domain

Tags: ajax, e-commerce, shopify

Is it possible, using apps/api/ajax etc to have a shopify cart send off a request to an external site which calculates a price based on the carts contents and adds an item to the cart with said price?

At the moment what I think might be a way forward is:

- Have a product "Handling" with a £0.01 price
- Write an app that includes some scripttags that add options to cart items
- When the options are changed the script contacts the external service with the cart contents and options
- External service can then add a quantity of the "Handling" product to the cart based on the calculation, customer can remove this item if they wish, which will reset their options

Is this a remotely feasible plan? Have I listed anything that just isn't possible or would be more appropriately done in another way?

Many thanks for any guidance.